# Database Design Model Entity Relationship Diagram n-entities relationship with 1:m entity - best practise

Tags: database, database-design, model

I have 3 entities (Clients, Reseller, Controlstation) and each of them can have multiple rows of another entity (Contacts). I've made an Entity Relationship Diagram with crow-foot notation to make that connection and I had to create three more entities (Controlstation_Contact, Reseller_Contacts, Clients_Contacts) as you can see in the diagram. Is that the best way to do it or could I make it better? Using the Primary Key of Client, Reseller and Controlstation in the Contacts entity as Foreign Key is not a good idea I think. Thanks for any advice

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's basically what you have to do in order to preserve referential integrity: create many:many relationships between each contact-having entity and `Contacts` itself, even though one contact may never relate to more than one other entity. Technically the relationship between `Contacts` and each junction table is one:many unless you add a unique constraint to `Contacts_Id` so the diagram isn't quite accurate.

You may feel tempted to cut down on the number of tables by creating a single intermediary entity with `Owner_Id`, `Owner_Type`, and `Contacts_Id` fields, where the `Owner_Type` indicates which of `Clients`, `Resellers`, and `Controlstations` is applicable. Don't give in! The database can't guarantee that `Owner_Id` refers to a value in more than one other table so you open yourself up to some bad data integrity headaches.

Based on your casing, this looks like SQL Server? If the RDBMS isn't set in stone, PostgreSQL has table inheritance which would allow you to federate the three contact-having entities behind a parent table. Then you could have a foreign key to the parent in your contacts table, or at worst have just one junction table to support a many:many relationship. It's not a standard RDBMS feature though so that's Postgres or nothing.

Comment: OK. Thank you for answering my question, dmafay. Your note with the unique constraint helped me... And yes, I am using SQL Server for this solution. Maybe I can switch to PostgreSQL.